# Windows authentication custom validation (from database)

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication, global-asax

I run an ASP.NET website that used forms authentication. In fact, user did not have to input anything - I took `Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]` and looked up this username in certain SQL database using custom class `EmployeeInfo`, then depending on the result the user was redirected to the default page or to error page that displayed different messages depending on the type of error:

Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Login.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        string UserName = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
        EmployeeInfo CurrentEmployee = EmployeeInfo.RequestDBInfo(UserName); // SQL magic here
        if (CurrentEmployee = null)
            Response.Redirect("AccessDenied.aspx?Message=NoInfo");
        else
            if (CurrentEmployee.Suspended = true)
                Response.Redirect("AccessDenied.aspx?Message=Suspended");
                if (CurrentEmployee.Expired = true)
                    Response.Redirect("AccessDenied.aspx?Message=Expired");
                    if (CurrentEmployee.Position = null)
                        Response.Redirect("AccessDenied.aspx?Message=NoPosition");
                    else
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(CurrentUserName, true);
    }
}
```

It was working okay until recently we had to switch to Windows authentication for security reasons. Now in case of invalid user my website does open `Login.aspx` page by default and redirects user to appropriate error page. But user can open any page by just typing its URL because no form authentication is performed of course and user is authenticated successfully by Windows.

**So my question is:**

What is best practice to implement additional check by database on top of Windows authentication? As far as I understand i need to alter `Application_AuthenticateRequest` in `Global.asax`?

Answer (score 0):

From the info given, tt sounds like you are using IIS with something like "Integrated Windows Authentication" enabled, "Allow Anonymous" disabled in the settings. All users to your site are getting authenticated between their web browser and the server (and the underlying network infrastructure). After being authenticated, IIS is checking the ACL on the website resource files, to ensure they are authorized to even request the file (via NTFS), and apparently this is set correctly so that the requests are being allowed to reach your ASP.Net code. Ok, so now that your code is reached, let's start with some strategy:

You mention Application_AuthenticateRequest. This is a great way to do it, as this gives you an injection point to write custom security code, after the requester has been authenticated by the configured security settings (IIS first, then anything set in your web.config included custom modules). Additionally, you can write your security code in just this one section, and it will get executed for every page on your site. When you write code for this method, you can check if the current user is authenticated by checking that `HttpContext.Current.User` is not null, and that `HttpContext.Current.User.IsAuthenticated` is `true`. You can get the user's network ID from the `User` property as you used to with `Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]'. Once you have the ID, you can do your database lookup, then redirect as appropriate.

For performance reasons, you may want to cache this info if that's acceptable under your security model. For example, a simple way would be to store a security object with their permissions in `Session`. Then you can check for that first, and if they user doesn't have an authenticated session yet, then do the database lookup, etc.